# when compiling C++ using VSCode command it uses is odd

Tags: java, c++, windows, visual-studio-code, cmd

I downloaded the things I needed to program C++ on Windows 10. I downloaded Cygwin64 and all the neccecary files to compile and run code. The only problem I see is that when i run it the command is different than what i normally see in tutorials. it says:

```
cd "c:\Users\codyr\Desktop\New folder\" ; if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
```

is there any reason for this? it does the same if i compile any java code as well.

```
cd "c:\Users\codyr\Desktop\New folder\" ; if ($?) { javac test.java } ; if ($?) { java test }
```

Comment: BTW, you can use [Linux Subsystem for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) directly instead of Cygwin on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Read `if ($?)` as did the previous command succeed. In other words, it stops executing the sequence of commands if a command fails. And I'm pretty sure that is PowerShell syntax (not DOS/CMD).

Comment: That is Linux shell commands running in Cygwin. It provides the environment to run Linux programs. The OP must be using some IDE or tool that automatically generates that command to go into the relevant directly, compile the source and then execute it.

Comment: @Azeem That does not look like bash to me. You could be right. `$?` is legal in bash. As are the `{}`, but the `cd` command slashes are not (those are backslashes, an escape in bash, but a path separator in the normal Windows environment). So I'm not 100% sure. Also it's ``c:\`` not `/cygdrive/c`... again, I don't think it's cygwin.